# Why doesn't this random variable have uniform distribution?

Tags: c++, cryptography, probability, discrete-mathematics

So, let's say we have a random variable X over {0,1}^1.  That means that X can take the value 0 or it can take the value 1.  My question is, why isn't this probability precisely 1/2 as it would be in the uniform distribution?  In other words, why can't we say anything about the probability distribution of X knowing that it can only take two values, and the value that it does take (either 0 or 1 in this case) is random?

Comment: Are you sure it's {0,1} and not the interval [0,1]?

Comment: Should be moved to the math board.

Comment: This should actually be moved to the Statistics board, not the Mathematics board.

Comment: Because the probability for each value depends on the _process_ producing those values.

Comment: @BobJohn there is no reason whatsoever they should be the same.

Comment: Paul, I am asking theoretically.  So, I guess I'm just confused about the intuition behind us having absolutely no insight on the probability of whether this value will be 0 or whether it will be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing [bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), which is also [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with n=1.

For this distribution your parameter is usually `p` - the probability of getting 1.

The probability of getting 1 and 0 varies, and might not be the same.

If you have `p=1/2` - it is a specific (very useful case) where the "experiment" is unbiased, and is often used for [statistical tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) - for testing if a certain data set is biased or not.

Comment: Beat me to it, just barely. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why, theoretically, a random variable defined on a set with only two values does not necessarily have uniform distribution, or are you asking why the C++ pseudo-random engine that you are using does not have uniform distribution?

It seems you are asking a theoretical question, in which case the answer is simply because that's how the distribution is defined (by you or someone else). Maybe I want to define a distribution such that 1 comes out 2/3 of the time. The size of the set does not influence distribution in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an example (two, actually).

Let X \in {0, 1} be a random variable that describes a coin toss; X=0 means heads, X=1 means tails, we assume the coin is fair and that it cannot land on its edge. In this case, P(X=0)=P(X=1)=0.5.

Now let Y \in {0, 1} be a different random variable that describes whether or not a light bulb burns out when you switch on the light; Y=0 means the light goes on, Y=1 means the bulb burns out. Let's say for the sake of argument that the probability of the bulb burning out is 0.0001, then P(Y=0)=0.9999 and P(Y=1)=0.0001.

What we see from this is that, to define a random variable fully, we need to specify not only the set of values it can take but also the underlying probability distribution. The specific distribution you choose will, of course, depend on the process you're trying to model.